# Using asycio to periodically call a function with a periodicy that depends on IO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm building a DJ lighting system with events that are triggered at certain beat intervals (i.e. flash strobe halfway between the next beat). The bpm (beats per minute) changes based on an external application and can never be assumed as fixed.

I would like to schedule a bunch of IO operations (flash strobe, trigger laser) to happen in the next beat by running a `scheduling_function` a few ms before the start of the next beat.

I know the time, in `event_loop` time units, when I would like the function to run (returned by `get_next_time_to_run()`).

I tried using the `event_loop.call_at()` function, with a recursive call, to continuously schedule the `scheduling_function` to be run right before the next beat. However, i get a RecursionError.

What might be a better way of setting this up. Here is my current code:

```
def schedule_next_frame():
    """This function is schedules the next frame (light, motor, lasers). It is trigged to run just before the next beat to give it time to prepare"""
    set_up_frame() #actual scheduling of IO
    frame += 1
    time_to_run = get_next_time_to_run(frame-0.1)
    loop.call_at(time_to_run, schedule_next_frame(frame))

print("Beginning YettiCubes2.0")
frame = get_current_beat()+1 #FIXME if this is really close to a beat boundary, we might tick over a beat before we can setup the next frame
loop.call_soon(schedule_next_frame())
loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to tell asyncio to run `schedule_next_frame(frame)` at the specified time. The following code doesn't do that:

```
loop.call_at(time_to_run, schedule_next_frame(frame))
```

Instead, it first calls `schedule_next_frame` recursively, and then passes the result of that call to `call_at`. Since the recursion is infinite, there never is any result, and you get an exception instead.

The correct way to tell `call_at` to run `schedule_next_frame(frame)` is:

```
loop.call_at(time_to_run, lambda: schedule_next_frame(frame))
```

The `lambda` expression will produce a function that, when called without arguments, invokes `schedule_next_frame(frame)`.